# How generate self signed certificate for signal opensource android app for our server

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, okhttp

I build https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android open source app and also set backend https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Server on amazon.

I have one problem with android app I'm getting error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

Because i'm using whisper.store file of whisper server. I need that same file for my server to work. I think that is something like pinned self signed certificate.

Please guide me how i can do that.

Comment: See [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the whisper.store and ad your server certificate in it.